# Property not found on selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am getting the following error:
A field or property with the name 'PageId' was not found on the selected data source.

This would make since if the PageId wasn't in the object - but it is.  Here is the aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel EnableViewState="true" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="pnlPagesDislay" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdMediaFilesetPages" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCommand="grdMediaFilesetPages_RowCommand"  CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1000px">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#49a4d4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PageId" HeaderText="Page ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="true" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LayoutId" HeaderText="Layout" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Images" HeaderText="Images" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="true" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" AccessibleHeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"> 
                        <ItemTemplate><span style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EditLink") %>">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID='RemoveLinkBtn' Text='Remove' CommandName='RemoveLanguageAttr' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LangAttrId") %>' runat='server' />
                         </span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#49a4d4" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#49a4d4" Font-Bold="True" VerticalAlign="Bottom" ForeColor="White" Wrap="true" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
_mediaFilesetPages = new List<MediaFilesetPage> {new MediaFilesetPage
                                               {
                                                   EditLink = "",
                                                   ID = "",
                                                   ImageFile = "testing.png",
                                                   LayoutId = "1",
                                                   PageId = "0001",
                                                   RemoveLink = ""
                                               }};
grdMediaFilesetPages.DataSource = _mediaFilesetPages;
grdMediaFilesetPages.DataBind();
```

And here is the MediaFilesetPage object:

```
internal class MediaFilesetPage
{
    public string ID;
    public string PageId;
    public string LayoutId;
    public string ImageFile;
    public string EditLink;
    public string RemoveLink;
}
```

Anyone have any idea of what the problem is?

Comment: I figured it out.  But I can't post the answer for 7 hours since I don't have a reputation of 100.  Will post when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your fields public properties:

```
internal class MediaFilesetPage
{
    public string ID {get; set; }
    public string PageId {get; set; }
    public string LayoutId {get; set; }
    public string ImageFile {get; set; }
    public string EditLink {get; set; }
    public string RemoveLink {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Guess I don't need to wait 7 hours to post the answer.  Thanks dude.